# Visual Studio 2022 Project Properties UI Property Evaluation

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard, visual-studio-2022

Maybe I'm missing something really obvious, but I can't for the life of me find the information I'm looking for anywhere.

In Visual Studio 2022, when you go to the Project Properties for a .NET Core or .NET Standard project, the new UI uses property evaluation to grab certain properties with a dollar sign syntax (e.g. $(MSBuildProjectName) or $(AssemblyName)) which correspond to MSBuild properties.  Immediately below these, it displays the evaluated property:
[image]
I'm trying to find out 2 things:

First, where are these properties being sourced from?

Second, is there a documented list of tags that can be used?

The only thing I was able to find that was close was this blog post by McKenna Barlow: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/revamped-project-properties-ui/

Any help to find this documentation is appreciated, since I have spent considerable time searching on the learn.microsoft.com site without success.